# Does dplyr::row_number() calculate row number for each obs? If so, how?

Tags: r, dplyr, row-number

On the [tidyverse website](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html)  reference, I saw two usage `mutate(mtcars, row_number() == 1L)` and `mtcars %>% filter(between(row_number(), 1, 10))`. It would be straight forward to think that the `row_number()` function is return the row number for each observation in the dataframe.

However, it has been emphasized in the documentation that the function is a window function and is similar to `sortperm` in other languages. As in the example:

```
x <- c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, NA)
row_number(x)
# [1]  5  1  4  2  3 NA
```

May I ask if this function is intended to report the row number for each observations? If it is, what is the logic flow behind the function call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `?row_number` says, `row_number` is equivalent to `rank(ties.method = "first")`, where `rank` (see `?rank`) returns the sample ranks of the values in a vector and using `"first"` results in a permutation with increasing values at each index set of ties:

```
row_number
# function (x) 
# rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep")
# <bytecode: 0x108538478>
# <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

So,

```
x <- c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, NA)
row_number(x)
# [1]  5  1  4  2  3 NA
rank(x, ties = "first", na.last = "keep") # I added na.last = "keep" to fully replicate row_number
# [1]  5  1  4  2  3 NA
```

since

```
sort(x)
# [1] 1 2 2 3 5
```

and we gave a lower rank to the first `2` due to `ties = "first"`.

Now when we use simply `row_number()` in `filter`, `mutate` calls, then indeed it seems to simply return a vector of row numbers, as can be found [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/hybrid/vector_result/row_number.h).